# Memory leak in Google PubSub Python client

Tags: python, memory-leaks, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-python

I am publishing messages indefinitely to Google PubSub using Python. I am publishing the messages in batches. I've set the batch_size as 20. I am publishing messages in 5 processes.

I executed below script in GCE with 1 CPU and 3.75 memory. After running for more than a hour, the GCE is out of memory and the publisher get crashed.

```
import json

from multiprocessing import Process
from google.cloud import pubsub

_PROJECT = 'google-project-id'
_TOPIC = 'sample'
_PROCESS_COUNT = 5


def publish(message_str, ps_batch):
    while True:
        ps_batch.publish(message_str)

def main():
    json_message = {'id': 1,'first_name': 'Karim','last_name': 'Bourdice','email': 'kbourdice0@purevolume.com','gender': 'Male','ip_address': '76.108.207.137','field1': '1MCwggd9g267ZBfq8p6KUR8RzXh1UARcBM','field2': '14MbkGizhAuYY9fjzA7UQ1x5sHfPEearMy','field3': '1BC7imHVSwT2xKmZBE6xVwGExXte4M87L7','field4': '1H2CPcuv9JvmnKV3Q9zxtZqZkvn86yyqFz','field5': '1GkanWfbWXxmriDt4vdDq5pb2wySL1nDiZ','field6': '1VKh8m3VcEt5xkfqj9BcCJfuL5nVc3nKZ','field7': '1NuruyCxMeL6YM8ouzD9aqAqFDfHzb6pak','field8': '1DB3Ac7uR5NJziSfJVLM1G2F6tW27SkZqN','field9': '1LdM4nGXPQkSKPTLkZFTbKHN9sAUpBGtSf','field10': '1LLCjdpVYy97u7kBdhHJcgycAZbdZ3R1xF','field11': '16FaG4qFomWMmv4Zv4F8MMUBkcJcEHHijY','field12': '1PXkwtCc4CWSp8BkecAvQubMs12GCvqdVu','field13': '1BqnENPGGDXn9S1FHn2pvwLtDDYu1QTjHL','field14': '1KckpoksBagHxANikRrRBC428srpxAqY5C','field15': '17Z3yPdFgkxEn29JaT89HshvVF4RbtMsMq','field16': '14QpaoakehbRnckiQd7Zte2nSRRGX695Wk','field17': '1wGqgYDSmfE9Q1ZH67GwLqNQmH2u7viRs','field18': '134KjLvr8ugwZK19wzL3V9i8fvmaBBjHQM','field19': '1JrUeWAvufRHXbMLSQeGLkjHJNx3XFM77A','field20': '19Botyc2ikY7V9XqRkJbnoJHWk2eVRxni5','field29': '1DjHXt1yecWxjuNPDMQDaAiCjBvDoEwZr1','field21': '1AZejYQWuuQi9DsGp27tHt7PdCRyBtLD8L','field22': '1AzK3J6vwwh8Xog5TJA48Uh223m5LwqRxz','field23': '12rSBAhFvgFMWbssYmSF3zCpDxmpSPxJV6','field24': '1C1QxVG8QphiRD2uzF6Mg86vRdwTARXpeW','field25': '1GRCqpUZ3oejbic59z16XWUYbw8GYdiq6f','field26': '1CH2yzHjehfuyVW9vw9NPTWX3yW5v2vTFg','field27': '1CCoa5aQPJ4Ya1FDKWrMceRReyptKcWV1N','field28': '1LJSmvzGWwDBLc1YTPaT2k1uAkiX8GjGpz'}
    message_str = json.dumps(json_message)
    batch_size = 20

    ps = pubsub.Client()
    ps_topic = ps.topic(_TOPIC)
    ps_batch = ps_topic.batch(max_messages = batch_size)
    print("Pushing messages to {0}".format(_TOPIC))

    processes = []
    for i in range(1, _PROCESS_COUNT):
        p = Process(target=publish, args=(message_str, ps_batch))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the stackdriver gce-memory-used chart.
[image]

You can see that memory-used is steadily increasing after running the above python script. And finally it got crashed. Please note that I am running this python script alone in this GCE and not any other application

Is there any workaround for this issue? How can I avoid memory leak here?

Comment: why put an infinite loop in `publish()`. If the publish rate is much high than consume rate, OOM might be happen

Comment: From the stackdriver report, I found that consume rate is as same as publish rate. The oldest acknowledge is 1000ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Luke and Tres, this is an issue with Google Python client which they agreed to fix.

Refer https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/62606697

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code, I am pretty sure the problem is here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/pubsub/google/cloud/pubsub/topic.py#L550

You have a single batch publishing messages over and over, but the message_ids returned are just added onto this list indefinitely until you OOM.

This is a bug. :-) You can work around it in the immediate term by setting `batch.message_ids` to an empty list every so often.

Comment: Thank you a ton for suggesting this! I was struggling with the OOM error in my publisher and indeed the culprit was that I was adding `self._publish_futures.append(future)` to track messages and later call `futures.wait(self._publish_futures, return_when=futures.ALL_COMPLETED)`, and over several million messages this caused OOM on my process. Thank you again! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than clearing `batch.message_ids` yourself, you can call `batch.commit()` from time to time (rather than relying purely on the "implicit commit at counter rollover" semantics).

Comment: Even when we call batch.commit(), batch.message_ids is added with returned value right?. I tried calling batch.commit after reaching certain count, but that doesn't help